# Python: How to fill out form all at once with splinter/Browser?

Tags: python, python-2.7, browser, splinter

Currently, I’m filling out the form on a site with the following:

```
browser.fill(‘form[firstname]’, ‘Mabel’)
browser.fill(‘form[email]’, ‘hi@hi.com’)
browser.select(‘form[color]’, ‘yellow’)
```

But the form gets filled out the form sequentially, one after the other. Is there a way to fill out the form all at once?

Thank you and will be sure to vote up and accept the answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browser has a method called: `fill_form(field_values)`

It takes a dict parameter, with the field names, and the values, and it fills the form at once.

So you'll use `browser.fill_form(dict)` instead of `browser.fill(field, value)`

More info about Browser's API and its methods here :

https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/driver-and-element-api.html

Comment: don't think I'm quiet understanding how it works. Do you mind showing a small example?

Comment: and how can I apply to `.select()` as well?

Comment: appreciate it! But I can still see that it is being filled out 1 at a time, then all at once. Is there a way to fill out the form all at once? Here is the dict I'm using: `form_dict = {
 ’form[firstname]’: ‘Mabel’,
 ‘form[email]’: ‘hi@hi.com’,
 ‘form[color]’: ‘yellow’
}`

Comment: According to the doc, fill_form() supports the following fields: text, password, textarea, checkbox, radio and select.
If your fields are named form[firstname], form[email] and form[color], it should work just by using browser.fill_form(from_dict)
I don't think there is an other way to do it "all at once"

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your answer!