# Simultaneously filling multiple form fields

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, splinter

I'm using Splinter to automate a basic order form in Python.

```
browser.fill_form({
    'formorder[billing_name]': 'Georges Perec',
    'order[email]': 'g.perec@oulip.fr',
    'order[tel]': '+ 33 (0)1 53 79 39 46',
    'order[billing_address]': 'La place Saint-Sulpice',
    'order[billing_city]': 'Paris',
    'order[billing_zip]': '75006',
    'order[billing_country]': 'FR'
    })
```

One poster in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43553630/python-how-to-fill-out-form-all-at-once-with-splinter-browser) recommended using browser.fill_form(dict) to fill out a form at once, but I'm still seeing the field values get filled in one-by-one. Am I doing something wrong, or does Splinter not support this function? If the latter, how could I achieve this functionality?

Comment: I don't believe the underlying WebDriver supports this feature. "Splinter" is most likely still calling `SendKeys()` on each element under-the-hood.

Comment: @Null511. Perhaps I could use Javascript to inject code instead?

Comment: Yes, you could. This should be significantly faster, but will probably get very messy. I believe it is also possible to inject javascript methods into the page, which might allow you to use JSON to transfer/serialize your form data.

Comment: @Null511 So would you recommend I use PhantomJS for my web driver, or would it be possible to achieve the same functionality without it?

Comment: It won't really matter what WebDriver you use in this scenario. Selenium exposes a common interface for all WebDriver functionality, so you will simply be executing Javascript strings.

Comment: PhantomJs is particularly useful when you are running headless (in Session #0, no visible UI). Chrome just released an update that supports this same behavior though, which [PhantomJs] has deemed the superior option.

Comment: @Null511 Got it. Thanks for your help!